# Accessing Test User Data with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am trying to get the friends of a test user using facebook graph api but it returns only the ids of the friends but not other details like first_name, last_name etc. This works though with real users. I specifically pass the fields that I require (the request looks something like this):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...&fields=id%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name%2Cgender%2Clocale%2Clink%2Clocation%2Cbirthday%2Creligion%2Crelationship_status
```

The access token is the token granted to the test user when the test user logs in to my application.

I have found a similar SO post but I am not sure what is the solution suggested.

[Query test users through Facebook Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4742372/query-test-users-through-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the App `access_token` and this can be tested in the Graph API Explorer by doing the following:

1. Go to the [Access Token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) and copy your app `access_token`
2. Go to [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and choose your app from the dropdown list.
3. Query `APP_ID/accounts/test-users?access_token=app_access_token` this would retrieve the test users
4. click on one of the ids (make sure this user is friend with at least one other test user) and change the query to look like: `TEST_USER_ID/friends?fields=first_name,last_name,gender&access_token=app_access_token`
5. You are done! :-)

---

**UPDATE**:
Based on the comments below, I've tried to retrieve the birthday of the test user's friends but the results were inconsistent.

- **Using test user's `access_token`:** IDs, birthdays and gender were retrieved but **not** names
- **Using App `access_token`:** IDs, names and gender were retrieved but **not** birthdays

Here's a simple code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
// You can retrieve this from: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
var app_access_token = "APP_ACCESS_TOKEN";
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID_HERE', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>

<table id="friends">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
function login(app) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var obj = {fields: 'name,gender,birthday', limit: 500};
            if(app)
                obj.access_token = app_access_token;
            FB.api('/'+response.authResponse.userID+'/friends', 'GET', obj, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if(response && response.data.length) {
                    var html = '';
                    for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += "<td>" + response.data[i].id + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + response.data[i].name + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + response.data[i].gender + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + response.data[i].birthday + "</td>";
                        html += "</tr>";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("friends").innerHTML += html;
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'user_birthday,friends_birthday'});

}
</script>
<button onclick="login();">List Friends With User Token</button>
<button onclick="login(1);">List Freinds With App Token</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result using one of my test user accounts:
[image]
The first three rows were retrieved with "*List Friends With User Token*" and the rest with "*List Freinds With App Token*".

***Bottom line, this needs Facebook attention!***

Comment: Using above, I am able to get the first_name, last_name of friends but not their birthdays. Moreover it is not clear why must the appAccessToken be used to get the details of friends?

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the update. Since this is a facebook issue, I am not sure if I can really mark this answer as accepted answer but doing it anyway because there is nothing more that can be done about it except reporting to facebook.

Comment: @DivKis01, well you should report it to Facebook as a bug (linking to this question), and if you got an *official* answer here "un-accept" my answer and accept the *official* one.

Comment: reported bug to Facebook which is logged here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/329960593684545