# Facebook test user - graph api does not return first name and last name

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

For a few days now, I am suddenly experiencing a strange behavior with the graph API access test users' friends.

When fetching the user objects of friends of my test user (which are test users as well), the first name and last name data is missing.

When I use the browser with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100001234567890
```

I get the response

```
{
   "id": "100001234567890",
   "name": "Dorothee Chengman",
   "first_name": "Dorothee",
   "last_name": "Chengman",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/people/Dorothee-Chengman/100001234567890",
   "gender": "female",
   "locale": "de_DE"
}
```

But when accessing it in my app with a request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100001234567890?access_token=imagineTokenHere&format=json
```

I get the response

```
{
   "id": "100001234567890",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001234567890",
   "birthday": "11/03/1980",
   "gender": "female",
   "locale": "de_DE",
   "updated_time": "2011-12-04T16:48:17+0000"
}
```

So, suddenly, the first name and last name are missing :-(

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Test User Data with facebook graph api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246147/accessing-test-user-data-with-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, being tracked in the bug tracker, it should only affect test users:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320132691332575

Comment: Thanks, Igy. Just found it also at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/329960593684545.